# How can time complexities be elements of others?

Tags: asymptotics

I have a problem that I solved, but I'm unsure if my answers are correct or not. I've never seen the implementation of time complexities as elements of others.

```
f(n) element of O(log(n))
g(n) element of theta(n)
```

Prove if the below are true are false, provide a counter example if it's false.

```
1) g(n) element of omega(f(n))
2) f(n)g(n) element of O(nlog(n))
3) f(n)g(n) element of theta(nlog(n))
```

Below are my attempts, which was just because I thought it was the logical solution. Any ideas on how I can go about solving these types of questions?

1) False, g(n) has a tight bound at (n). If it had a lower bound of f(n), then g(n) should allow log(n), but that's too high of a complexity.

2) True

3) False, f(n) having an upper bound of log(n) implies it could be even faster. Setting a tight bound contradicts that wherein it cant go faster.

Comment: You posted the same thing almost literally, got feedback about why your question is bad, and got a link to a comprehensive answer to your question. Deleting and reposting is not appropriate -- look, you already wasted poor Denis' time!

Comment: Your titular question does not seem to have anything to do with your post. Note that your question has nothing to do with algorithms or "time complexities" -- it's all about asymptotic bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the 1) is true: omega means "at least", and $O$ means "at most". You now that $g(n)$ is in $n$, which is at least $\log(n)$.

2) is indeed true

For 3) you don't have enough information: it is only true if $f$ is in $\theta(log (n))$ which you don't know, so 3) could be true or false.
You can give a counter example where it is false: $f(n)=\log(\log (n)))$ and $g(n)=n$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I was just wondering how your counter example works, why is it log(log(n))?

Comment: Anythin in $O(\log n)$ but not $\theta (log n)$ is ok, you can also take $\sqrt{\log n}$ for instance, or even a constant.